# Paypal Marketplace Platform - How to implement partner fee?

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-marketplaces

So I've followed the Paypal documentation to the best of my ability.

Specifically these:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/get-started/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/seller-onboarding/before-payment/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/immediate-capture/
```

I'm able to onboard my sandbox seller, and I'm able to create an order (via the steps/example in immediate-capture link) however, when I access the HATEOAS (checkoutnow) to redirect the buyer to the check out form, when I click submit to finalize the checkout, it just redirects to the same page without error messages.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, can you guide me through it? I can't find much resources online about this.

I've only been trying it via CURL as per their documentation. I've also tried this without a webhook and with a valid one. Same result.

Right now I'll be trying to actually implement it in code, but I'm doubting that will work.

I've been stuck on this for days. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. If you have information, feel free to unload it for me.

My goal for using Paypal Marketplace Platform is to be able to onboard sellers and take a percentage of their sales called the partner fee.

Update:

I added a return_url/cancel_url like @Preston PHX mentioned and it did solve my redirect / refresh issue. However that didn't fix my orders not being approved issue. What did help me capture the payment ultimately is change the payee.email_address value into payee.merchant_id value in the create order API call.

I have a new issue now, in which I cannot find where the platform fee went... It's not in the sandbox account attached to the platform app. I'll create a new post for it.

Comment: For this site, questions about code should include your code that you are having an issue with also.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I did not add them as they were simple curl requests taken from the links I've provided. I'll edit them in as soon as I sanitize them of my keys and tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it just redirects to the same page without error messages.

This happens because you didn't specify a `return_url` to come back to. Normally the checkout is displayed [using the JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) and no redirects at all, so that return_url is not a required parameter. Redirecting is an old integration method, for old websites.

As for a partner_fee , you need to onboard sellers with the [Partner Referrals API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/seller-onboarding/before-payment/) for that to be valid. Using the Partner Referrals API in the live environment probably requires account approval by PayPal, so make sure you aren't integrating something you don't have permission to use.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, I will look into adding a return_url. My issue with this is, even if I don't have a return_url, when I check the order's status via its GET API, the status hasn't changed (still CREATED when I assume it should be APPROVED or CAPTURED).

I could be wrong though as when I attached the webhooks, it does say that an order has been approved. But when I try to capture it via API, it tells me that it cannot be captured and needs approval. This is what confuses me about this. In any case, I'll try adding a redirect and see what happens.

Comment: As for partner fee, I've followed the instructions in the link for my seller. While I am testing these in sandbox, we've also been approved as partners so I imagine have the permissions for this already unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX. Your suggestion about the return_url helped with the redirect issue. I'll accept your answer since it did solve part of my problem for this post. Thanks!